# Как установить скроллинг для виджета

Tags: c++, qt

Делаю виджет — диаграмму времени, которая будет отображать посчитанные моменты времени для разных групп объектов:

[image: Диаграмма времени. То, что хочется реализовать]

Высота (количество строк) будет задаваться количеством групп. Сам виджет должен иметь фиксированную высоту и ширину, однако если групп моментов будет больше, чем возможность отобразить на виджете заданной высоты, то должен быть вертикальный скролл. Аналогично, если объектов хотя бы в одной группе больше, чем сейчас отображено, то должен быть горизонтальный скролл.

Вопрос номер ноль:
Как виджету задать фиксированный размер, выходя за который появлялся бы скролл по строкам клеточек. Но если Количество этих строк умещалось бы, то отрисовка на нижней границе виджета.

Вопрос номер один: 
Как прикрутить скролл к моему виджету?

Вопрос номер два: 
Окно, в котором будет отображаться эта временная диаграмма, не будет иметь возможности ресайза, всегда постоянный размер. Нужно ли делать layout?

Пока всё выглядит так для двух групп объектов:

[image: Текущее состояние]

.h файл диаграммы:

```
#pragma once
#include <QWidget>
#include <qscrollarea.h>

class TimeDiagram : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TimeDiagram(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~TimeDiagram();

    void draw( QPainter  *painter);
    unsigned int getRowHeight();
    QScrollArea *diagramArea;
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
};
```

Отрисовка при создании окна:

```
GraphicScaleDialog::GraphicScaleDialog(OutputData *outputData, QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::GraphicScaleDialog) {
    ui->setupUi(this);
    data = outputData;
    diagramWidget = new TimeDiagram();
    diagramWidget->diagramArea = new QScrollArea(this);

    unsigned int height = diagramWidget->getRowHeight() * data->outputSettings.flowQuantity;
    diagramWidget->diagramArea->setGeometry(30, 50, 1080, static_cast<int>(height));
    diagramWidget->diagramArea->setWidget(diagramWidget);
    diagramWidget->diagramArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
}
```

Comment: ну вы можете пихнуть свой виджет в QScrollArea. На основной виджет бросьте layout, в него QScrollArea, а внутри него уже всё остальное.

Answer (score 0):

```
QScrollArea* area = new QScrollArea;
area->addWidget(pointerToyourWidget);
area->show();
```